# How to set run cocos2d tests in Xcode 4.2?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.2

I an a beginner. I have problem running cocos2d tests in Xcode 4.2 since I cannot customize toolbar in xcode 4.2 anymore. How do I set the active target and executable? Or anyone knows the workaround for running the tests? Any helps are much appreciated! Thanks a lot!

Comment: There should be a scheme for each test if you open the cocos2d.xcworkspace file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find this by editing scheme in your target. In scheme bar above your project where you select simulator and device, click your project and edit scheme in drop down. There you can set the executable. :) 
hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

In XCode 4.2, the bar will default to ActionManagerTest when you've loaded the project sucessfully. Clicking it will allow you to change tests.

Also note, that the official cocos2d tutorial tells you to open **cocos2d-ios.xcodeproj** to begin exploring; but to actually run the tests, you need to open **cocos2d-tests-ios.xcodeproj**.